# Get TOP 8 PERCENT then insert into another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a scenario where I need to calculate the top 8 percent of records based on scores attributed to each artist/record as determined by 5 different judges over 3 categories.

To do this I use the following in a stored procedure

```
SELECT TOP 8 PERCENT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MEM.Id,
         EN.artistName, EN.dateAdded, EN.voteStatus, 
         ES.enterNextRound, ES.notified, ES.voted,
         GR.genre,
         ES.entrantId AS bandID,
         ES.rnd2Feedback AS feedback, ES.compositionVote,
         ES.vocalsVote, ES.originalityVote,
         (SELECT COUNT(Voted)
          FROM recEntrantStatus
          WHERE voted = 1
            AND roundId = 2
            AND entrantId = ES.entrantId) CountVoted,
         (SELECT (COUNT(Voted)/*-1*/)
          FROM recEntrantStatus
          WHERE roundId = 2
            AND entrantId = ES.entrantId) CountTotalVotes,
         (SELECT COUNT(Id)
          FROM recMembers) TotalJudges,
         (SELECT coalesce(SUM(compositionVote),0)
          FROM recEntrantStatus
          WHERE roundId = 2
            AND entrantId = ES.entrantId
            AND voted = 1) SumTotalComposition,
         (SELECT coalesce(SUM(vocalsVote),0)
          FROM recEntrantStatus
          WHERE roundId = 2
            AND entrantId = ES.entrantId
            AND voted = 1) SumTotalVocals,
         (SELECT coalesce(SUM(originalityVote),0)
          FROM recEntrantStatus
          WHERE roundId = 2
            AND entrantId = ES.entrantId
            AND voted = 1) SumTotalOrig,
         (SELECT SUM(compositionVote + vocalsVote + originalityVote)
          FROM recEntrantStatus
          WHERE roundId = 2
            AND entrantId = ES.entrantId) TotalVoteScore
     FROM 
         recMembers AS MEM
     LEFT JOIN 
         recEntrantStatus AS ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
     LEFT JOIN 
         recEntrants AS EN ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
     LEFT JOIN 
         recGenre AS GR ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
     WHERE 
         MEM.Id = 4
         AND ES.roundId = @input) q
ORDER BY 
    TotalVoteScore DESC, compositionVote DESC, 
    originalityVote DESC, vocalsVote DESC
```

Now, to prepare the competition for the next round I need to take this result set and create a new record for each row, once for each of the full set of judges(currently approximately 20 in total). So that would be 20 records for each of this top 8% recordset (approximately 12 entrants / records). This therefore should result in approximately 12*20 records being inserted.

In previous rounds I simply selected 'ALL' entrants who had a bit field used as a marker to indicate that they were to progress to the next round. I did this with the following code:

```
INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
    SELECT 
        r.entrantId, (@input + 1), j.judgeId /*Now getting tblJudges Id*/, 0, 0, 0
    FROM 
        recEntrantStatus r
    -- Get all of the judges
    CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT Id AS judgeId 
         FROM recMembers 
         WHERE Privilege >= 2) AS j
    WHERE 
        r.roundId = @input
        AND r.voted = 1
        AND r.enterNextround = 1
```

So, my problem is essentially how do I combine these two queries so as to take the top 8% from the current round, then add a new record for each of 20 judges for each of this top 8% of entrants?

Unfortunately it's not a simple case of replacing the CROSS JOIN SELECT with the one that retrieves the TOP 8%.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose your query using CTEs that identify your TOP 8 PERCENT members and all of your judges, then cross join the two so you have the multiple records to insert.

Here is the skeleton of the query, which you can fill in with all of your properties and necessary conditions.

```
WITH Members AS
(
    --note, for a CTE, all columns in the select must have a name (or you must specify the column names above next to the CTE name)
    SELECT TOP 8 PERCENT mem.id, entrantId, ... FROM recMembers [mem] ... ORDER BY ...
),
Judges AS
(
    SELECT Id [judgeId] FROM recMembers WHERE Privilege >= 2
)
INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
SELECT m.entrantId, ...
FROM Members m, Judges j --cross join of your top 8% members and all of your judges
WHERE ...
```

You can do this in other ways such as with a derived table expression in your example, but I think the CTE approach is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try with that and see how I get on.

Comment: With a minor tweak to my own SQL and that appears to work perfectly. Thanks for the help!!!